# gnuplot format xK or xM

Tags: format, gnuplot

For the format of x-axis, current I am using the following command in pngcairo terminal:

```
set format x "%.sK"
```

Which recognizes numbers from 100K to 900K but when it gets to 1 million it prints "1K" instead of "1000K".

what is the command to automatically set the label to "xK" before 1 million and to "xM" after 1 million?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kind of labels are controlled by gnuplot's own format specifiers (see doc for `gprintf`):

```
set format x '%.s%c'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This partially solved the problem. Now on y axis I have 500k, 1M, 2M, 2M!
even when I set the `set ytics 500000` no  1.5M is appearing. 
Do you know how should I fix that?

Comment: You must set the number of decimals to use, e.g. `%.1s` for one decimal position